# Autohint user input as he enters text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs

What I'm struggling to find a way to achieve is a way to auto complete the input itself while users type.

As an image worth more than a thousand words I'm basically looking to replicate the same behaviour that you can experience in the city search input of Airbnb

[Image to see the input in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxTCb.png)

Does anyone have an idea of how I can make an input that have a similar behaviour ?

PS : I'm not looking for a code implementation, just hints about how do you think this can be achieved

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795843/how-to-implement-a-google-suggest-like-input-field

Comment: @DanielaMaia yes that's it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking at is called as typeahead. You can use Twitter's typeahead. There are plethora of tutorials, documentation and code snippets available for typeahaed implementation.  [Here](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) is an example of twitter's typeahead.

Comment: Thank you man ! That's exactly what I was looking for, I didn't know how it was called :)